# Android Firebase Junit4 mocking database. How to mock database children?

Tags: android, firebase, testing, junit4, powermock

Need some help with testing my app.
I want to verify viewmodel fun **writeNewTask()**. It has to add **Task** object into database under the parents called **tasks** and personal **id** of every Task.

```
fun writeNewTask(name: String?, orphanage: String?) {
        val id = database.push().key!!
        val task = Task(id, name, orphanage)
        database.child("tasks").child(id).setValue(task)
    }
```

I'm using PowerMock. So, that's how my test looks like

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(JUnit4::class)
@PrepareForTest(FirebaseDatabase::class, AddTaskViewModel::class, DatabaseReference::class)
@PowerMockIgnore("org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "android.*", "androidx.*")
class AddTaskViewModelTest {

    @Mock
    lateinit var mockedDatabase: FirebaseDatabase
    @Mock
    lateinit var databaseReference: DatabaseReference
    @Mock
    lateinit var viewModel: AddTaskViewModel

    @Before
    fun before() {
        viewModel = PowerMockito.mock(AddTaskViewModel::class.java)
        databaseReference = PowerMockito.mock(DatabaseReference::class.java)

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(AddTaskViewModel::class.java)
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(DatabaseReference::class.java)

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(FirebaseDatabase::class.java)
        `when`(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()).thenReturn(mockedDatabase)

        mockedDatabase = PowerMockito.mock(FirebaseDatabase::class.java)
        `when`(mockedDatabase.reference).thenReturn(databaseReference)
    }

    @Test
    fun writeNewTaskTest() {
        val id = "1"
        `when`(databaseReference.key).thenReturn(id)
        val name = "name"
        val orphanage = "orphanage"
        val task = Task(id, name, orphanage)

        viewModel.writeNewTask(name, orphanage)

        verify(databaseReference)
            .child("tasks")
            .child(id)
            .setValue(task)
    }
}
```

And I catch this error. After debugging I figured out that **child("tasks")** is *null*

```
databaseReference.child("tasks");
-> at com.example.application.viewModel.AddTaskViewModelTest.writeNewTaskTest(AddTaskViewModelTest.kt:59)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Wanted but not invoked:
databaseReference.child("tasks");
-> at com.example.application.viewModel.AddTaskViewModelTest.writeNewTaskTest(AddTaskViewModelTest.kt:59)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the reference you have to your database is not the same as you have in the ViewModel. So let's pretend you have a ViewModel that gets a database in it's contructor as such:

```
class AddTaskViewModel(private val database: FirebaseDatabase): ViewModel()
```

So, to test your ViewModel you need to create its instance, not mock it. Which in your code should look like:

```
@Before
fun before() {
    databaseReference = mock(DatabaseReference::class.java)
    mockedDatabase = mock(FirebaseDatabase::class.java)
    `when`(mockedDatabase.reference).thenReturn(databaseReference)

    viewModel = AddTaskViewModel(mockedDatabase)
}
```

Also you don't need PowerMockito to test this, Mockito itself is enough

Comment: it helped but test is still failed. java.lang.IllegalStateException: databaseReference.push() must not be null

Comment: you need to mock that method too

Comment: Ouch. mb missclicked

Comment: Thank u! it's alive!